# How can I set default keyboard-layout for individual applications?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, usability

How can I set default keyboard-layout for individual applications?

Example:

- For Chrome: Russian
- For Visual Studio Code: English

I know Windows has an auto option for this, but often it doesn't work correctly, and 
I also have a third language. Maybe I could remove it from the language list, using it only through a special shortcut, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>?

Comment: Consider installing some Linux distribution such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](http://debian.org/). On both of them, switching keyboard layout is *very* easy.  My daughter (teaching Russian, and typing russian text) is doing that all the time. Then configuring a keyboard layout change at a single keyboard press is a matter of minutes. And both Chrome and VisualStudioCode runs on these Linux distributions

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for reply, but Linux not satisfies all my needs.

Comment: That was a comment, not a reply. Good luck. Microsoft sells some support. Did you consider contacting them? And [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is opensource, so you can improve the code and recompile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Settings -> Devices -> Typing
2. Go to Advances keyboard settings. Enable "Let me use a different input method for each app window"
3. Go to Chrome and select Russian keyboard. Then go to Visual Code and select English keyboard.

**Reference:** 
[How to Turn On or Off Use Different Keyboard Layout for each App Window in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102999-turn-off-use-different-keyboard-layout-each-app-window.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I did the same, when I change the language (for example, to English for writing this comment) and switch to another window as it remembers the last language, which subsequently brings inconvenience.

Comment: Try using Left Shift+Alt, when changing the keyboard layout of the app. It should stick (at least when the window(s) are opened. I have not tried to close and re-open).

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: Works without problems with Chrome for me. I use the language selector next to the clock in the task bar to switch language.